# Why have 2 storyboards when there is AutoLayout?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, autolayout

With iOS6 there is AutoLayout, which is a constraints based layout system. I guess it is somewhat comparable to Android's flexible XML layouts.

I am kicking off an iOS6 project and want to you AutoLayout. This app will be universal. It will have some views that are extremely similar between 2 device families. Others views on the iPad will be 2 or more controllers in the iPhone views.

From what I understand, UIViewControllers can be setup with other child UIViewControllers. This means there's 2 ingredients to building a universal view in both devices.

So my question is, why is there a need for 2 storyboards? I can see that the iPad storyboard has some additional controls etc. There's also problems of scaling font sizes and other variables between the two device types. Can anyone offer advice on how to not have duplicated views on 2 storyboards and use AutoLayout efficiently to achieve a good universal app?

Much appreciated.

Comment: you can't! You must use it both.

Comment: Just because it is a bigger device doesn't mean it just uses the same UI but bigger. The entire way the device is used changes between iPhone and iPad. UI concepts are completely different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iPad UIs tend to not be simply enlarged versions of iPhone UIs. There's more screen space to use, and there are custom iPad-only interface elements (e.g. UISplitViewController).

If in your case the different devices have very similar layouts, then yes, you could just use one layout with autolayouts and it could work ok. However, I'd recommend against it in most cases. It's clearer to just have two layouts, one for each kind of device.

The final decision is up to you. Maybe you could try the single layout strategy, using autolayouts, and see if you come up against any particular problems.

Comment: I wish I could +1 this again.

Comment: Been a while but I ended up with a hybrid solution of sort. I do have an iPad storyboard to create the iPad layouts. Some of the panels (UIViews) in the storyboards are blank. I have a set of MasterIPadViewController, MasterIPhoneViewControllers that does some clever loading of views from the other storyboard if outlets and options are set. Some of the iPad VCs extend the iPhone ones and add the extra functionality to the UI. This made sure maximum code reuse and maximum UI flexibility. (60Hz is the name of the app.)

Comment: I work on iOS and Android. The fragment and some of the Java class hierarchy stuff offers a lot more flexibility to reuse stuff. But yes, they do come with their own set of extra complexity. I think my next universal app architecture will be quite a bit diff.

Answer (score 2):

It is my experience that it would probably be easier for you to not use the storyboards and make everything programmatically, but that is more opinion based.

Your question is a little vague, but my opinion would be to setup views with auto-layouts as you mentioned, and then have a controller that uses those views. What will end up happening is that you will have view within views within a controller, and this will allow you to control all the layouts while being able to pick and choose what goes where, depending on the device.

It might help some if you gave a more specific example to run with. TO be honest though, this is something that interests me as well, and I look forward to seeing other ideas on this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done a couple of sample projects to test out what are the ways to achieve something like this and I've gotten some good success out of this. I think this deserves an entire blog post -- which I will write and post a summary as a answer here. I have been able to load just 1 storyboard.